# Multiple icons open in tray bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon

I am working on a Windows application, and when I run this application, there are multiple icons appearing on the tray bar:

[image]

and when I mouse-over these icons, they disappear.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        notifyIcon1.Icon.Dispose();
        notifyIcon1.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    base.OnClosed(e);
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Either you're not cleaning up the icons yourself, or your application crashes for some reason and has no chance to clean up after itself.

Comment: @J.Steen Can you please tell how should i clean icon ?

Comment: Unless you post any *relevant* and *concise* code, no-one is likely to be able to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369197/system-tray-icon                                 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969758/winforms-notification-icon-duplicates-in-the-system-tray                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788638/disappearing-system-tray-icons

Comment: Check those links maybe you will find your answer.

Comment: @Mr_Green: You are drawing a conclusion rather quickly here: Just because something happened to you, too, doesn't make it a computer virus right away. There's a good chance that there is something wrong with the user code shown.

Comment: @GurbaxSinghBhangal: Why are you swallowing exceptions with an empty `catch {}` block? Given your very question, shouldn't you be *extremely* interested to see whether your `notifyIcon1` disposal steps raise an exception?

Comment: @stakx I removed my comments

Comment: `catch {}`? Don't ever do that!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I close my system tray icon to bring up the full application in a program I wrote a while back:

NOTE: this fits well in an event handler in the code behind, hence this.Show() and this.Activate()

```
            NotifyIcon sysTrayIcon = sender as NotifyIcon;
            sysTrayIcon.Visible = false;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            this.Show();
            this.Activate();
```